# Google Maps Directions API

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm looking for all kinds of feedback: style issues, missed corner cases, performance etc.

My code is regarding Google Maps Directions API that is a service that calculates directions between locations using an HTTP request.

`overview_polyline` contains a single points object that holds an encoded polyline representation of the route.

`steps` contains detailed directions for walking or driving steps in transit directions.

`legs[]` contains an array which contains information about a leg of the route, between two locations within the given route.

`html_instructions` contains formatted instructions for this step, presented as an HTML text string.

`start_address` contains the human-readable address (typically a street address) resulting from reverse geocoding the start_location of this leg.

`end_address` contains the human-readable address (typically a street address) from reverse geocoding the end_location of this leg.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


public class TF {

    private String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
    private String mainUrl = url;

    private String origin = null;
    private String destination = null;

    private String key = "";
    private String keyMatrix = "";

    private String urlMatrix = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?";
    private String urlMatrixCopy = urlMatrix;

    private List<String> list = null;
    private long[][] times = null;
    private String mode;

    private LinkedList<String[]> html_instructions_list = new LinkedList<>();

    public void setOrigin(String origin){
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination){
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public void setListMatrix(List<String> list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void setMode(String mode){
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public long[][] fetchMatrixResult() {

        urlMatrix = urlMatrixCopy;
        urlMatrix += "origins=";

        int length = list.size();
        times = new long[length][length];
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                times[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        if(length == 1) {
            urlMatrix += list.get(0);
        } else {
            for(int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
                urlMatrix += list.get(i) + "|";
            }

            urlMatrix += list.get(length - 1);
        }
        urlMatrix += "&destinations=";

        if(length == 1) {
            urlMatrix += list.get(0);
        }
        else {
            for(int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++){
                urlMatrix += list.get(i) + "|";
            }
            urlMatrix += list.get(length - 1);
        }

        urlMatrix += "&mode=" + mode;
        urlMatrix += "&key=" + keyMatrix;
        System.out.println(urlMatrix);

        String json = retrieveURLData();
        System.out.println("JSON: ");
        System.out.println(json);
        String[][] matrix = buildTimeMatrix(json, length);
        for(String[] row: matrix){
            System.out.print("| ");
            for(String element: row) {
                System.out.print(element + " | ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("\nTIME MATRIX\n");
        for(long[] row: times){
            System.out.print("| ");
            for(long time: row){
                System.out.print(time+" | ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n");

        return times;
    }

    private String retrieveURLData() {

        try {

            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            URL urlPath = new URL(urlMatrix);
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlPath.openStream()));
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1) {
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
            }

            return buffer.toString();

        } catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String[][] buildTimeMatrix(String json, int length){

        System.out.println("\n\n");
        String[][] matrix = new String[length + 1][length + 1];

        try{
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray) jObj.get("destination_addresses");
            for(int i = 1; i < length + 1; i++) {

                matrix[0][i] = jArray.getString(i - 1);
                matrix[i][0] = jArray.getString(i - 1);
            }

            jArray = (JSONArray) jObj.get("rows");
            for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject row = (JSONObject)jArray.get(i);
                JSONArray elements = (JSONArray) row.get("elements");

                for(int j = 0; j < elements.length(); j++) {
                    String text;
                    long timeValue;

                    JSONObject element = (JSONObject) elements.get(j);
                    JSONObject duration = (JSONObject) element.get("duration");
                    text = (String) duration.get("text");
                    timeValue = duration.getLong("value");

                    matrix[i+1][j+1] = text;
                    times[i][j] = timeValue;
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException je){
            je.printStackTrace();
        }

        return matrix;
    }

    public String[] getHtmlInstructions(int index){

        return html_instructions_list.get(index);
    }

    public String fetchResult() {

        url = mainUrl;
        url += "origin=" + origin;
        url += "&destination=" + destination;
        url += "&mode=" + mode;
        url += "&key=" + key;

        try{

            System.out.println(url);

            int read;
            URL urlPath = new URL(url);
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlPath.openStream()));
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1) {
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
            }

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
            System.out.println(buffer.toString());

            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) json.get("routes");
            if(array.length() == 0){
                return "NO ROUTE";
            }

            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) array.get(0);

            JSONArray array1 = (JSONArray) obj.get("legs");
            JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject) array1.get(0);
            String origin = obj2.getString("start_address");
            String destination = obj2.getString("end_address");
            String header = origin +" --> "+destination+"\n";
            JSONArray array2 = (JSONArray) obj2.get("steps");
            String[] html_instructions = new String[array2.length()+1];
            html_instructions[0] = header;
            for(int i = 0; i < array2.length(); i++){
                JSONObject obj2a = (JSONObject) array2.get(i);
                String html = obj2a.getString("html_instructions");
                html_instructions[i+1] = html;
            }
            html_instructions_list.addLast(html_instructions);

            JSONObject obj3 = (JSONObject) obj.get("overview_polyline");
            return obj3.getString("points");

        }  catch(IOException | JSONException ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     private long[][] times = null;
> ```

So this starts as unset.  In the method `fetchMatrixResult`, you initialize it.  You set values in it in `buildTimeMatrix`.  Why?  You never use those values.  The only time that you read from `times` is to return it from `fetchMatrixResult`.  But each time that you call `fetchMatrixResult`, you throw away the old `times` array and create a new one.

The only way that this pattern works is if you call `buildTimeMatrix` from `fetchMatrixResult`.  Since you don't use `times` anywhere but those two methods, consider enforcing this relationship.  Remove the object field `times` and replace it with a local variable in `fetchMatrixResult`.  Replace it with a parameter in `buildTimeMatrix`.

That way, you don't have an object field hanging out for the life of the object even though you only use it when one method is called externally (`buildTimeMatrix` is only called internally).  And the usage pattern is enforced rather than maintained by protocol.

> ```
>                     String text;
>                     long timeValue;
>
>                     JSONObject element = (JSONObject) elements.get(j);
>                     JSONObject duration = (JSONObject) element.get("duration");
>                     text = (String) duration.get("text");
>                     timeValue = duration.getLong("value");
>
>                     matrix[i+1][j+1] = text;
>                     times[i][j] = timeValue;
> ```

It seems like we could shorten this.  For example:

```
                    JSONObject element = (JSONObject) elements.get(j);
                    JSONObject duration = (JSONObject) element.get("duration");
                    String text = (String) duration.get("text");
                    long timeValue = duration.getLong("value");

                    matrix[i+1][j+1] = text;
                    times[i][j] = timeValue;
```

But I think that I'd go ahead and say

```
                    JSONObject element = (JSONObject) elements.get(j);
                    JSONObject duration = (JSONObject) element.get("duration");

                    matrix[i+1][j+1] = (String) duration.get("text");
                    times[i][j] = duration.getLong("value");
```

There doesn't seem to be a compelling need for intermediate variables here.

The main argument in favor of the intermediate variables is that they act as comments.  But I would think that a better solution would be to name `matrix` and `times` more descriptively.

> ```
>     private String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
>     private String mainUrl = url;
> ```

This could be just

```
    private static final String MAIN_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
```

Then

> ```
>         url = mainUrl;
> ```

could become

```
          String url = MAIN_URL;
```

Again, no need to carry around a field when a local variable will do.

> ```
>         try {
>
>             int read;
>             char[] chars = new char[1024];
>             URL urlPath = new URL(urlMatrix);
>             StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
>             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlPath.openStream()));
>             while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1) {
>                 buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
>             }
>
>             return buffer.toString();
>
>         } catch (IOException ioe){
>             ioe.printStackTrace();
>         }
> ```

You never close the `reader`.  You could add an explicit `close`, but I would prefer to use the [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) form:

```
        URL urlPath = new URL(urlMatrix);
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlPath.openStream()))) {

            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1) {
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
            }

            return buffer.toString();

        } catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This will handle a number of edge cases that you might miss if doing it manually.